# VBA How to get text from lines below when using Line Input?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get copy information from an email saved as a .txt file to an excel sheet.
The issues I am running in to is when I use a Do Loop with the Line Input function I can not get information from text lines that are not on the current line. I would also like the code to copy the line containing the deliminator.

This is the code I am using:

```
 intFreefile = FreeFile
 Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp567.txt" For Input As #intFreefile
 lngRecordsInEmail = 0
 Do Until EOF(intFreefile)
     Line Input #intFreefile, strText
     If InStr(1, strText, strDelimiter) > 0 Then
         If InStrRev(1, strText, strDelimiter) = 1 Then
         ' if last character in line = deliminator then
         ' how do i get the text on 2 lines below?

         Else
         ws.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = strText
         End If

         If blColourCell Then
             ws.Cells(lngRow, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        End If
         strText2 = strText2 + 1
         lngRow = lngRow + 1
         lngTotalRecords = lngTotalRecords + 1
         lngRecordsInEmail = lngRecordsInEmail + 1
    End If
 Loop
 Close
```

Comment: Then you need to add code inside your loop, after finding your delimiter, to read ANOTHER line.  Make that a loop if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite method which is also faster than looping through the file contents is to read the entire text from the file into an array in one go and then work with the array. This will also give you more control to retrieve text from the 2 lines that you want.

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

```
Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
Dim i As Long

intFreefile = FreeFile

'~~> Open file and read it on one go
Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp567.txt" For Binary As #intFreefile
MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #intFreefile, , MyData
Close #intFreefile '<~~ Close the text file after reading from it

'~~> This array has the entire contents from the text file
strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
    '~~> Last character in line = deliminator
    If Right(strData(i), 1) = strDelimiter Then
        Debug.Print strData(i)
        Debug.Print strData(i + 1)
        Debug.Print strData(i + 2)
    '~~> Else if the deliminator is somewhere else
    ElseIf InStr(1, strData(i), strDelimiter) Then
        Debug.Print strData(i)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Upvoted, except I would strongly advise against hard-coding the file number. Use a local variable and assign it to `FreeFile` so as to let VBA determine what file number is free to use.